# Check if Value doesn't exist in other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-relationship

Hello i have the following problem.

I have this ER-Diagram
[image]

I need to select all the persons that did not publish a journal or conference paper in the year they published their PhD theses (PhD is type field in Theses). My Problem is i achieved it when i only check if he didn't publish a paper, but when i have both i fail what do i wrong?

```
Select count(akey)
from persons 
WHERE (Select theses.year 
       from persons 
          inner join theses on persons.akey = theses.akey 
       Where theses.type = 'PhD') not in ((Select year 
           from persons 
             inner join authpapers on persons.akey = authpapers.akey 
             inner join papers on authpapers.pkey = papers.pkey 
             inner join journals on journals.jkey = papers.jkey) 
 and (Select year 
      from persons 
        inner join authpapers on persons.akey = authpapers.akey 
        inner join papers on authpapers.pkey = papers.pkey 
        inner join conferences on conferences.ckey = papers.ckey));
```

It says the part starting from not in isn't type of boolean but how should i make it otherwise?

Comment: One hint: `Exists`

Comment: A main issue with your query is that you are selecting `from persons` in your subqueries that are not related to the person in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Your NOT IN clause basically reduces down to `NOT IN (queryResultJournals AND queryResultPapers)`. It's trying to AND the two query results, which is not what you want (and is why you're getting a not a boolean error). You should replace the and with a UNION or UNION ALL, which joins the two query results into one, which will then work in the NOT IN clause.

```
Select count(akey)
from persons 
WHERE (Select theses.year 
       from persons 
          inner join theses on persons.akey = theses.akey 
       Where theses.type = 'PhD') not in ((Select year 
           from persons 
             inner join authpapers on persons.akey = authpapers.akey 
             inner join papers on authpapers.pkey = papers.pkey 
             inner join journals on journals.jkey = papers.jkey) 
 UNION (Select year 
      from persons 
        inner join authpapers on persons.akey = authpapers.akey 
        inner join papers on authpapers.pkey = papers.pkey 
        inner join conferences on conferences.ckey = papers.ckey));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative: You can collect all publications (thesis, conferences and journals) and then aggregate to find persons that in one year published their thesis plus conferences or journals.

```
with published as
(
  select akey, type, year from theses where type = 'PhD'
  union all
  select ap.akey, 'conference', c.year
  from authpapers ap 
  join papers p on p.pkey = ap.pkey
  join conferences c on c.ckey = p.ckey
  union all
  select ap.akey, 'journal', j.year
  from authpapers ap 
  join papers p on p.pkey = ap.pkey
  join journals j on c.jkey = p.jkey
)
select *
from persons
where akey in
(
  select akey
  from published
  group by akey, year
  having bool_or(type = 'PhD')
  and not ( bool_or(type = 'conference') or bool_or(type = 'journal') )
)
order by akey;
```

The aggregation `bool_or` can be read as "at least one" or "any".

We don't know whether your database allows the same paper issued both as jounal and conference. Or whether a person can have multiple PhD theses (maybe several attempts?). Above query looks at all years a person published something and if it finds at least one year a person published a PhD thesis and jounals or conferences, it shows that person.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count if you can use `exists()`

---

```
SELECT *
from persons pe -- I need to select all the persons
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT SELECT * -- that did not
       FROM theses th 
        JOIN authpapers ap on pe.akey = ap.akey
        JOIN papers pa on ap.pkey = pa.pkey 
        JOIN journals jo on jo.jkey = pa.jkey -- publish a journal paper
        WHERE th.type = 'PhD'
        AND th.akey = pe.akey
        AND th.year = jo.year  -- in the same year
        )
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM theses th
        JOIN authpapers ap on pe.akey = ap.akey
        JOIN papers pa on ap.pkey = pa.pkey
        JOIN conferences co on co.ckey = pa.ckey  -- or publish a conference paper
        WHERE th.type = 'PhD'
        AND th.akey = pe.akey
        AND th.year = co.year -- in the same year
        );
```